# How do I find the Chart Id of an existing chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

How do I go about finding the the ChartID for a chart I've already created in google sheets.

I've searched through the documentation and can't get anything to work.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no methods for directly searching a chart ID. But you can retrieve all chart IDs in a Spreadsheet using the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API. [The official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts) says as follows.

> The placeholder chartId is also used to indicate the ID of a given chart. You can set this ID when creating a chart with API, or allow the API to generate one for you. You can read the IDs of existing charts with the spreadsheet.get method.

#### Endpoint:

For example, in order to retrieve only chart IDs, when `fields` of `sheets/charts/chartId` is used, the endpoint is as follows.

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheetId ###?fields=sheets%2Fcharts%2FchartId
```

#### Result:

When 1st sheet and 2nd sheet have 2 charts and 1 chart, respectively, the following result is returned. If you want to search the chart ID, you can search it from the following result.

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "charts": [
        {
          "chartId": ###
        },
        {
          "chartId": ###
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "charts": [
        {
          "chartId": ###
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Charts](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in Ruby.

```
require 'google/apis/sheets_v4'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

response = service.get_spreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID)

response.sheets.each do |sheet|
  title = sheet.properties.title
  if title = sheet_name
     unless sheet.charts.nil?
        charts = sheet.charts
        charts.each do |chart|
           chart_id = chart.chart_id
           puts chart_id
        end
     end
  end
end
```